# How to create a Github pages website with private access?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a Github organization, and I am going to create a private or internal repo in that organization. That repo is going to host a Github Pages site. But I want the site to be private and not publically accessible by people outside the organization. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to create a private Github Pages site is to have GitHub Enterprise Cloud ([as seen here](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-01-21-access-control-for-github-pages)). Otherwise, there is no official way to make a private repo's site private.

Therefore your best bet is using Priv-page: https://github.com/apps/priv-page

Comment: Priv-page is shut down as of April, 2022.